# Cannot activate Conda environment

Tags: anaconda, miniconda

I installed miniconda and I created an environment:

```
conda create --prefix /path/to/a/directory/Python36 python=3.6
```

Then I tried to active it:

```
conda activate /path/to/a/directory/Python36
```

But I got this error message:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run
$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

But when I run `condo init --all`, I nothing changes, everything is already initialized.

```
...
No action taken.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually you activate an environment by name:

```
> activate myenv
```

Mac/Linux users have `> source activate`.  Newer conda versions may use `> conda activate`.

In your case, what is the name of your environment?  You can [list existing environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-your-environments):

```
> conda env list
```

If you find an env other than `root` or `base`, activate it as mentioned above.

In the future, consider [creating environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) with a name to easily access later:

```
> conda create -n myenv ... python=3.6
> activate myenv
```

Note: `...` indicates arbitrary optional flags.

Comment: Thanks, the key was to use `source activate`instead of `conda activate`. And I could not use a name because I needed to specify a specific directory for installation.

Comment: Great.  `conda activate` is a new thing.  Good to see the old way still works.  I suspect you can add a name specify a location.  `> conde create --name myenv --prefix path/to/python/ python=3.6`

Answer (score 0):

The following codes under Windows terminal solve my same problem:
`C:\Users\username\anaconda3>cd condabin`
`C:\Users\username\anaconda3\condabin>conda.bat activate envname`

and get it done:
`(envname) C:\Users\username\anaconda3\condabin>`